# Mobile phone call or mailto doesn't work at all

Tags: android, html, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

I have a really small app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">Send Mail</a>
    <a href="tel: +18543458975">Call</a>

    <button onclick="document.location.href = 'tel:+1-800-555-1234'">Click me</button>
    <button onclick="document.location.href = 'tel:+18543458975'">Click again</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When I build and run it the links doesn't work at all.

Two weeks ago (on another app) this worked perfectly but now it doesn't work on this neither my older apps.

I ran out of ideas!

**What is is happening?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using protocols other than http/https is now whitelisted, and blocked by default.

http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/08/04/android-351.html
http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/09/08/cordova-361.html

You simply need to add mailto and tel protocols to the whitelist.

See the "External Application Whitelist" section of http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html for instructions on what to add to the whitelist starting in 3.6.0.

Because the security vulnerability surrounding this was fixed in 3.5.1, you don't want to use 3.5.0 or you'll be vulnerable and get a warning from the Google Play store.

Comment: you were right.It works now. I'm way too new into mobile development to know all this things

Comment: Great - adding `<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />` and `<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes" />` lines to `config.xml` solves the problem.

Answer (score 14):

*I guess things have changed again with the new release.*

You must install the [cordova plugin whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist):

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

or if you want to save the reference to your **config.xml** file:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist --save
```

and that you have to add the intent to your **config.xml** file:

```
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
```

You can find more info [here](http://devgirl.org/2015/04/24/apache-cordova-newsflash/).

Answer (score 0):

I seemed that the bug was from cordova version 3.6 I was working on , so I installed an older version (3.5) and now it works perfectly!